# Spring boot Tomcat – Enable/disable directory listing

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I have `spring boot` application and i'm using `embedded tomcat` as web server.
I have problem with listing directories. 
I want to now how could i `enable or disable listing directories` in embedded tomcat.
In none spring boot application we can do it adding code below in `web.xml`:

```
<init-param>
       <param-name>listings</param-name>
       <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

how can i `Enable/disable` directory listing in spring boot?

I have found only question below in stackoverflow but didnt help.

> [Embedded Tomcat directory listing for spring-boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004870/embedded-tomcat-directory-listing-for-spring-boot-application)

Comment: I even doubt if you enable it it would work. As there aren't directories there are only jar files and class path entries as everything is in a single jar and it isn't extracted to the file system (as a regular deployment on tomcat would do).

Comment: is it a jar or war

Comment: @M.Deinum yes you are right, it doesn't extracted to the file system in order to list directories inside of it.

Comment: @gladiator my project package is in `war`

Comment: And it won't get extracted. So as mentioned enabling file listing won't help.

Comment: you can add a controller or restservice which list all files in a particular directory

Comment: Refer to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004870/embedded-tomcat-directory-listing-for-spring-boot-application/46509688#46509688][1]

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to `spring-boot`, pretty much everything can be micro-managed via configuration files.

You can pass `init-param` values to the embedded container using the following properties

```
server.servlet.jsp.init-parameters.*= # Init parameters used to configure the JSP servlet.
```

in your case,

```
server.servlet.jsp.init-parameters.listings=false
```