# Path based vulnerability in java spring application

Tags: java

Below content related to qualys scanned report :
Kindly suggest how I need to resolve the path based vulnerability of application what we need to add ,

WASC WASC-15 APPLICATION MISCONFIGURATION

WASC-16 DIRECTORY INDEXING

WASC-17 IMPROPER FILESYSTEM PERMISSIONS

Times Detected 3

CVSS Base 2.1 CVSS Temporal1.9

Details

Threat

A potentially sensitive file, directory, or directory listing was discovered on the Web server.

Impact

The contents of this file or directory may disclose sensitive information.

Solution

Verify that access to this file or directory is permitted. If necessary, remove it or apply access controls to it.

Comment: Show the the code which is complained

Comment: What's your Web server? Are you using Springboot?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44254804/spring-boot-tomcat-enable-disable-directory-listing - Springboot configuration to disable directory listing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing - apache Httpd server

Comment: There are similar configurations available for all Web Servers. If you would provide more info on your setup, we can help you better.

Comment: Spring boot ,webspher server using