# Why JSP recompilation needs some time interval?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp, tomcat

I'm using JSP (please do not mention Thymeleaf...) in spring boot 3.2.0 on M1 Mac, and I found that if I consecutively update the samea JSP file, the recompilation doesn't happen right away and the page shown in the browser doesn't update. If I wait for, say, 5 secs, it happens.

So, I mean,

```
When I update a JSP file and immediately access it:
↓
(The page is recompiled and updated, then I wait a few seconds)
↓
Update JSP, immediate access again
↓
(The page is recompiled and updated)
```

However, if I do it without any interval:

```
Update JSP, immediate access
↓
(The page is recompiled and updated, and then immediately again)
↓
Update JSP, immediate access
↓
(The recompilation does not happen and the page is not updated...)
```

... is what happens.

Is there any setting that fixes this situation?

For your information, this is the view, `index.jsp`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
hello world
</body>
</html>
```

controller:

```
package com.example.mysite.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class RootController {
  @GetMapping
  public String index() {
    return "index";
  }
}
```

`application.properties`:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
# These don't work
# server.jsp-servlet.init-parameters.modificationTestInterval=0
# server.jsp-servlet.init-parameters.development=true
```

## Edit

Here are more details and informations.

I've tried creating a minimum case. Here's the code and its behavior (see the included `behavior` video):
https://fastupload.io/grsd2af5JAQE9ql/file

Starting from creating a spring boot project from IntelliJ,

- `pom.xml`
- `application.properties`
- `RootController.java`
- `index.jsp`

are the only updated files.

I actually noticed that, in the video, even the first editing wasn't showing up on the browser immediately... it seems the behavior isn't very stable. Anyway, I hope you can reproduce what I mention, or at least you can see it in the video.

Comment: I am sorry but to exactly understand your problem, are you trying to say that the change you make in your jsp file is not immediately seen in the browser?, but after a few reloads?

Comment: How do you update your JSP file ?
I mean in your controller and JSP file there is no dynamic updatable field. so do you update jsp file manually with spring-boot-dev-tool ?

Comment: @FlavianDiolD "the change you make in your jsp file is not immediately seen in the browser?" -> It's not. "but after a few reloads?" -> After a reload after a few seconds.

Comment: @Javid It's manual. I change it to, say, `hi world`, with apring-boot-dev-tool. As for the browser reload, I usually use browsersync fyi, but manual refresh produces the same result.

Comment: So it takes time for IDE to find the change and save it then if it's required for compilation. If you change JSP file rapidly IDE just saves changes and loads the last change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You point out the following properties that are not working in your situation

```
# These don't work
# server.jsp-servlet.init-parameters.modificationTestInterval=0
# server.jsp-servlet.init-parameters.development=true
```

According to the current (so 3.2) [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.servlet.jsp.init-parameters), the property prefix for `init-parameters` is `server.servlet.jsp.init-parameters.*`

So you should try to set

```
server.servlet.jsp.init-parameters.development=true
server.servlet.jsp.init-parameters.modificationTestInterval=0
```

Extract of [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/jasper-howto.html) of properties set for Tomcat :

*development*

> Is Jasper used in development mode? If true, the frequency at which JSPs are checked for modification may be specified via the modificationTestInterval parameter.true or false, default true.

This property is overridden in SpringBoot to be `false` by default (see `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.Jsp.Jsp()` constructor where they add an init-parameter of `development` to `false`)

*modificationTestInterval*

> Causes a JSP (and its dependent files) to not be checked for modification during the specified time interval (in seconds) from the last time the JSP was checked for modification. A value of 0 will cause the JSP to be checked on every access. Used in development mode only. Default is 4 seconds.

If you already have springboot-devtools, the `server.servlet.jsp.init-parameters.development` parameter is already set to `true`, in order to avoid handling dev mode and production mode configuration properties (reference [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.devtools.property-defaults))

You should also check for [excluding resources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.devtools.restart.excluding-resources) documentation in order not to trigger a full restart by spring-boot devtools when changing a JSP file

> By default, changing resources in /META-INF/maven, /META-INF/resources, /resources, /static, /public, or /templates does not trigger a restart but does trigger a live reload.

**EDIT**
By adding the following property, you also disable internal caching in Tomcat and your JSP should always get up-to-date :

```
server.tomcat.resource.allow-caching=false
```

Comment: Tried it. It definitely makes the things better, but I actually think the effect is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77633921/why-jsp-recompilation-needs-some-time-interval/77673762#comment136935799_77635650 . I mean, yes, now the options seem to be "applied", but he immediate update doesn't work sometimes yet...

Comment: Did you disable the browser cache ? Or add header cache-option in the response ? What do you mean by the immediate update doesn't work sometimes ? Is your SpringBoot trying to restart after changing the JSP ?

Comment: I don't set any cache setting manually. The browser cache is disabled. It takes a couple of seconds sometimes to be shown the updates in the browser, when I update the JSP file. Please see my attached file as I mentioned: https://fastupload.io/grsd2af5JAQE9ql/file

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. At least the init-parameters seems OK now :)

Comment: Could you try adding the following class to debug `org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler` (check of outdated is done in `isOutDated` method) and check if you got `Compiler: outdated: XXX` output ?

Comment: I just run in debug mode and in fact the jsp doesnt get to tomcat updated context after two consecutives short-updates : the following if statement `if (targetLastModified != jspRealLastModified.longValue())` return `false` since both JSP and Java Generated class file share the same lastModificationDate. I don't know if it's a bug or not but actual config is working as expected

Comment: I'm actually checking the same part. It seems the problem is from that part maybe...?

Comment: FYI: the behavior of `Compiler: outdated: XXX` is exactly as you mention.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the behaviour is from the fs not returning latest info from the file or a file sync delay. Behaviour of Compiler is as expected. I'll check later for this :-)

Comment: Have to dig further but the jsp file is a CachedResource

Comment: Updated answer with `server.tomcat.resource.allow-caching=false` property

Comment: Adding `server.servlet.jsp.init-parameters.development=true`, `server.servlet.jsp.init-parameters.modificationTestInterval=0` and `server.tomcat.resource.allow-caching=false` works perfetly. You saved my life!!!

Comment: Glad to have helped you with this. And learned also some tips for myself

Answer (score 1):

There's a property to configure a `JSPServlet` on embedded instance of Tomcat server which is used by default in `spring-boot` using `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency.

The `modificationTestInterval` property is set by default to 4 second. This is a time to wait untill the next modification of JSP is occured.

See the official Tomcat documentation [Jasper 2 JSP Engine How To](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/jasper-howto.html). There're two parameters needed:

> - `modificationTestInterval` - Causes a JSP (and its dependent files) to not be checked for modification during the specified time interval (in seconds) from the last time the JSP was checked for modification. **A value of 0 will cause the JSP to be checked on every access**. Used in development mode only. Default is 4 seconds.
> - `development` - Is Jasper used in development mode? If `true`, the frequency at which JSPs are checked for modification may be specified via the `modificationTestInterval` parameter. `true` or `false`, default `true`.

So, you can change the default configuration for embedded Tomcat as follows

```
server.jsp-servlet.init-parameters.modificationTestInterval=0
```

You should check if Tomcat is running in `developer` mode by default in Spring Boot.

If you are looking the ways to modify options of embedded Tomcat in Spring Boot then see [SpringBoot Embedded Tomcat JSPServlet Options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28863340/573032).

> you could just add the parameters to your `application.properties` file as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)
>
> Look for:
>
> ```
> server.jsp-servlet.init-parameters.*= # Init parameters used to configure the JSP servlet
> ```

Comment: I've set `server.jsp-servlet.init-parameters.modificationTestInterval=0` and restarted the spring boot now, but the result doesn't change...

Comment: you also need to set `server.jsp-servlet.init-parameters.development=true`

Comment: Tried it, but the same result...

Comment: Did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28877134/573032)?

Comment: I think your link is about spring 2. Excuse me, I'm using spring 3.2.0 and (saying "hey it's a different version" could be kinda rude but) I'm honestly not sure how the code in your link applies in this case...

Comment: The versions of the software and libraries should be included in the question. The link should give you an idea how to configure `JSPServlet` programmatically in SpringBoot rather than `application.properties`.

Comment: Okay, I've added the version, thanks.

Comment: I've tried converting the linked snippet to v3 compatible, and it actually made it slightly better... although it still takes a couple seconds sometimes. Hmm...